# Using Include Query through Indirect Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join

I have an `users` table where it has many `group users` and has one `user account summary`. All of these tables have the same field `user_id`. I was hoping to include user account summary into a group users query. So I would like to do this...

```
@group.group_users.includes(:user_account_summary)
```

But it's telling me that the associated name was not found. How can I fix the query to include the user's account summary with group user's? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@group.group_users.includes(:user => :user_account_summary)`. Since `user_account_summary` is an association on `User` instead of `GroupUser`, the association has to pass through `User`.

You could also add a `user_account_summary` relation to `GroupUser` that matches `user_id` to `user_id` if you want to use the association more often:

```
class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_account_summary, :primary_key => 'user_id', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
```